# Function component keeps rerendering over and over

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

My react function component keeps re-rendering itself over and over until the browser crashes.

The only solution i could find was entering [] with my constant at the end of useEffect().

```
function getNestedObject(nestedObj, pathArr) {
  return pathArr.reduce(
    (obj, key) => (obj && obj[key] !== "undefined" ? obj[key] : undefined),
    nestedObj
  );
}

function Genres() {
  const [genreList, setgenreList] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    let results = "";
    axios({
      url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/genre/movie/list?",
      method: "GET",
      responseType: "json",
      params: {
        api_key: "00000000000",
        language: "en-US"
      }
    }).then(result => (results = result.data.genres));

    let a = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      let name = getNestedObject(results, [i, "name"]);
      a.push(name);
    }
    setgenreList(a);
    console.log(genreList);
  }, [genreList]);
  return <div>test</div>;
}
```

I have also tried it without the useEffect which gives the same looping result.

I have `<Genres />` down in the render.

Comment: results will be an empty string inside your for loop, as the axios response won't have returned yet, does it throw any errors? :) So it will return `undefined` for name and your a will contain that 10 times

Comment: Yeah, the axios get i can fix, it currently prints out empty arrays in the console.log. But my problem is that it keeps rerendering nomatter what :(

Comment: try an empty array as the second argument ?

Comment: Can you show where you use this component?

Comment: Are you only wanting it to run once when the component mounts? If so, you need to pass a second argument to `useEffect()`, which should be an empty array `[]`.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. This is how useEffect is intended to function. 

The second parameter should be an array containing the values that would trigger useEffect *should they change*. 

You should probably read up on it more... https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: @cullanrocks he wants his code to run only once. It's not dependent on `genreList`, so the `useEffect` isn't supposed to watch it.

Comment: A combination of the answers of @Rahul and @Sim Dim, worked :)
I added the ```setgenreList(a);``` inside the ```then``` function and now it uses axios correctly and then i used 
```useEffect(() => {
    //code here
    }, [])
```
Which solved the constant rerendering of the component. Thankyou everyone for helping so fast :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Its happening because of you are calling

```
    setgenreList(a);
```

at useffect , genreList change its state, UseEffect run again

when you are writing

```
  useEffect(() => {}, [genreList])
```

then it will be called everytime when you call its setter **setgenreList**

you may write

```
useEffect(() => {
    //code here
    }, [])
```

Answer (score 1):

Actually, you are generating an empty array every time and updating the state with a newly generated array every time, hence useEffect loops infinitely (check [] === []). Also you have an obvious error in the code: the state update doesn't depend on axios result at all, since you don't wait for response results ("then" block is executed after setgenreList(a)). Use state update inside "then" function.

Answer (score 1):

I thought I would add a small answer that does a similar implementation, and how you could handle at least conditions based on your current implementation ( based on the [Rules of Hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html) )

For one, you seem to follow the documentation quite literally, when you call `useState` you provide it with the default value for it, and you set it as `0`, where it should rather be an empty array (since you fill an array afterwards with it)

For the `useEffect` you don'tneed the second parameter as an empty array ( although that indicates that the effect should never rerun ), you can leave it empty as well, but you could verify if your array has already values in it, when not, you can do your network call (you use [axios](/questions/tagged/axios), but for simplicities sake, I use the native `fetch` instead)

```js
const { useState, useEffect } = React;

const container = document.querySelector('#container');

const BreedList = () => {
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect( () => {
    if (!breeds.length) {
      fetch( 'https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all' )
        .then( resp => resp.json() )
        .then( result => {
          setBreeds( Object.keys( result.message ) );
        } );
    }
  }, [breeds] );
  
  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Breeds</h1>
      { breeds.map( breed => <div key={ breed }>{ breed }</div> ) }
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render( <BreedList />, container );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```